# How to use Java Access Bridge correctly?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, java-access-bridge

Here is my code:

```
BOOL bRet = initializeAccessBridge();
if (!bRet)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("ERROR at initializeAccessBridge"), _T("ERROR"), 0);
}
shutdownAccessBridge();
```

I am trying to initialize Java Access Bridge, but initializeAccessBridge always return FALSE, and I cannot find any explanation of error handle from 
[Oracle® Java Access Bridge Installation and Application Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/toc.htm).

I wanna know that what is wrong with my initialization of JAB, or how to handle this error.

P.S., I can run JavaMonkey and JavaFerret with correct configuration.

Comment: Was this code written in C or C++?